# How to convert elements(string) to integer in tuple in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I am still learning Python and currently solving a question on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-tuples) where I am thinking of converting input(String type) to tuple by using built-in function(tuple(input.split(" ")).

For example, myinput = "2 3", and I want to convert it to tuple,such as (2,3). However,if I do that, it will, of course, give me a tuple with String type, like ('2', '3').  I know that there are a lot of ways to solve the problem, but I'd like to know how to convert elements(str) in tuple to integer(in Python) in most efficient way.

See below for more details.

```py
>>> myinput = "2 3"
>>> temp = myinput.split()
>>> print(temp)
['2', '3']
>>> mytuple = tuple(myinput)
>>> print(mytuple)
('2', ' ', '3')
>>> mytuple = tuple(myinput.split(" "))
>>> mytuple
('2', '3')
>>> type(mytuple)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(mytuple[0])
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: a trivial generator comprehension + tuple will do. (but map is in fact a little shorter)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
myinput = "2 3"
mytuple = tuple(map(int, myinput.split(' ')))
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a more readable way to convert a string to a tuple of integers. We use list comprehension.

```
myinput = "2 3 4"
mytuple = tuple(int(el) for el in myinput.split(' '))
```