# How to convert a python tuple of string to tuple of integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. Could anyone help me with this problem?

I want to convert a tuple of nested strings with an unknown number of nested tuples like:

```
(('1','2'), ('3','4'), ('5','6'), ... ('100','101'))
```

to a tuple of nested integers:

```
((1,2), (3,4), (5,6), ... (100,101))
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Added 'What if the number of nested tuples was unknown?'

Comment: `li = [(int(x),int(y)) for x,y in a]` like this? where `a = (('1','2'), ('3','4'))`

Comment: What if the tuple has a lot of nested tuples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert elements(string) to integer in tuple in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168806/how-to-convert-elementsstring-to-integer-in-tuple-in-python)

Comment: `a = [tuple(map(int, i)) for i in a]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need a recursive function.

```
def get_int_tuple(rows):
    result = []
    for row in rows:
        if isinstance(row, tuple):
            if all(map(lambda s: isinstance(s, str) and s.isdigit(), row)):
                result.append(tuple(map(int, row)))
            else:
                result.extend(get_int_tuple(row))
    return tuple(result)


tupl = (('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6'))

arr = get_int_tuple(tupl)
print(arr)

tupl = ((('1', '2'), ('3', '4')), ('5', '6'))

arr = get_int_tuple(tupl)
print(arr)
```

result:

```
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` to map string values to integer:

```
tupl = (('1','2'), ('3','4'))

print(tuple(tuple(map(int, x)) for x in tupl))
# ((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if the number of nested tuples was unknown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression with a small helper function:

```
t = (('1','2'), ('3','4'), ('5','6'))

func = lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x)

tuple(func(i) for i in t)
# ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
```