# How to take a list of tuples and change the tuples from strings to integers

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the code

```
l = [('1',['3','1','2']),('2',['4','5','2'])]
```

How do I make it:

```
l = [(1,[3,1,2]),(2,[4,5,2])]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert elements(string) to integer in tuple in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168806/how-to-convert-elementsstring-to-integer-in-tuple-in-python)

Comment: Since tuples are immutable - you should iterate over your collections and recreate it.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `int` function while iterating using list comprehension

```
r = [tuple([int(i),[int(k) for k in j]]) for i,j in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be generalised using recursion:

```
def to_ints(item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [to_ints(e) for e in item]
    elif isinstance(item, tuple):
        return tuple(to_ints(e) for e in item)
    else:
        return int(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple approach is to remove the quotes and parse it back to a list

```
 l = eval(str(l).replace("'", ""))
```

Comment: Please do not use `eval` for something like this that can be accomplished easily using built-in features.

Comment: Well you might be right that eval  not necessarily a best practice, but in this case I can't see a drawback to it. Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: There's some existing discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Comment: I read that post before posting my answer. None of the disadvantages stated are relevant to the OPs question other than the time difference which is still not a drastic difference. Actually using eval here saves time of looping on the list and it's sublists.