# How to Merge and Sort three arrays having values like software versions in python

Tags: python, sorting

Recently, I have been trying to solve a problem, which asks me to sort different software versions. The inputs are given in string type like below.

```
 input_list = ['1.1.1','1.2','2.0','1','1.11','0.2','3','2.1.0']
```

Applying sort function without splitting the inputs the output obtained is

```
output_list=['0.2','1','1.11','1.2','1.1.1','2.0','2.1.0','3']
```

Here `1.11` is printed before `1.2`. This order wrong as in case software versions.

Thus I segregated values of `input_list` based on the number of dots **(split it wrt `'.'`)** and appended it to three respective arrays. After mapping the values to `int` I sorted the three arrays and remapped to the values to `str`

This is how the sorted arrays look:

```
list1= ['1.1.1','2.1.0']
list2= ['0.2', '2.0','1.2', '1.11']
list3= ['1','3']
```

The idea now is to append all the above values in ascending order to one final array. I am having trouble in this part because, simply appending and sorting will result in the same error mentioned above. This problem is because python considers `1.11 < 1.2` when the values are in string type.

What we can do to merge the three arrays to get an output like this

```
output_list = ['0.2','1','1.1.1','1.2','1.11','2.0','2.1.0','3']
```

Comment: Idea: [convert version strings to tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168806/how-to-convert-elementsstring-to-integer-in-tuple-in-python), append all tuples to a list, sort the list (of tuples).

Comment: @jarmod hey, thanks for your answer. But I have edited my question for more clarification on the issue I face while sorting.

Comment: Your modified output list appears to be wrong. It should be: `['0.2','1','1.1.1','1.2','1.11','2.0','2.1.0','3']`.

Comment: Unusual that 1.1.1 is considered a higher version number than 1.11. Are you sure?

Comment: @jarmod, I messed up, You are the best.. I have edited the question once again. Thanks for correcting me. Pardon me, I am a noob here.

Comment: Here's an example of what I was talking about earlier (using tuples, merge, sort): `result = sorted([tuple(map(int, v.split('.'))) for li in [list1, list2, list3] for v in li])`. That will yield a sorted list of version tuples. If you need those formatted as string e.g. `(1,2,3)` => `"1.2.3"` then you can add code to do that.

Comment: @jarmod you are a life saver... Thanks for your help

Comment: My Reputation is 1. As a noob I do not know how to do it... can you please advise @jarmod

Comment: Oh I see, not to worry in that case. So, for future questions, be sure to include the code of the attempt that you have made to solve your problem and show its output (along with the desired output, which you did actually include here). That will reduce/prevent downvotes and closure. Stack Overflow wants to help solve problems and it will respond positively if you have made a reasonable effort to code a solution but it's not a code-writing service.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your advice, I am happy to say that I have learnt many coding tips( including tips on how to ask questions in Stack Overflow ;-) ) from my first question itself. Thanks for your help once again