# How to convert a tuple list string value to integer

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, integer, tuples

I have the following list:

`l = [('15234', '8604'), ('15238', '8606'), ('15241', '8606'), ('15243', '8607')]`

I would like to converted it such that the tuple values are integers and not string. How do I do that?

Desired output:

`[(15234, 8604), (15238, 8606), (15241, 8606), (15243, 8607)]`

What I tried so far?

```
l = [('15234', '8604'), ('15238', '8606'), ('15241', '8606'), ('15243', '8607')]
new_list = []
        for i in `l:
            new_list.append((int(i[0]), i[1]))

        print(tuple(new_list))
```

This only converts the first element i.e. 15234, 15238, 15241, 15243 into int. I would like to convert all the values to int. How do I do that?

Comment: `int()` is what does the conversion, so why are you only calling it on `i[0]` and not `i[1]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert elements(string) to integer in tuple in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168806/how-to-convert-elementsstring-to-integer-in-tuple-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most concise way is via a list comprehension:

```
>>> [tuple(map(int, item)) for item in l]
[(15234, 8604), (15238, 8606), (15241, 8606), (15243, 8607)]
```

This takes each tuple in `l` and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)s the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function to each member of the tuple, then creates a new tuple out of them, and puts them all in a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the second numbers into integers the same way you did the first. Try this:

new_list.append((int(i[0]), int(i[1]))